# In app product can be bought twice or more

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

The alert Item already purchased does not show up and the user is able to buy the product again with the same account. He's charged twice after an uninstall. Why does the alert with "Item already purchased" does not show up?

I'm using ionic 1.x and this [plugin](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase)

This is the code I use:

```
var productIds = ["ch.tapsy.colosseo"];

  var spinner = '<ion-spinner icon="dots" class="spinner-stable"></ion-spinner><br/>';

  $scope.loadProducts = function() {

      console.log("loaded inapp products");


    if ($state.current.name === "info") {
      $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://domain.ch/pois.php"
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        console.log("success");
      }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.errorinapp = "yes";
      });
    } else {
      $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://domain.ch/pois.php"
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        console.log("success");
      }, function myError(response) {
        $state.go("inappe")
      });
    }

    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: spinner + 'Loading...'
    });
    inAppPurchase
      .getProducts(productIds)
      .then(function(products) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.products = products;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(err);
      });
  };


  $scope.buy = function(productId) {
      console.log("buy clicked");

    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: spinner + 'Acquisto in corso...'
    });
    inAppPurchase
      .buy(productId)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log('consuming transactionId: ' + data.transactionId);
        return inAppPurchase.consume(data.type, data.receipt, data.signature);
      })
      .then(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('sold', 'true');
        save("isUnlocked", true);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        if (state == "l2") {
          $state.go("12")
        }
        if (state == "l1") {
          $state.go("11")
        }
        if (state == "l5") {
          $state.go("15")
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(err);
      });

  };

  $scope.restore = function() {


    console.log("IT WORKS");


    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: spinner + 'Ripristino degli acquisti in corso...'
    });
    inAppPurchase
      .restorePurchases()
      .then(function(purchases) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(purchases);
        if (!purchases.length) {
           console.log("Sorry, there's nothing to restore. You haven't purchased anything using this account before!");
         } else {
             localStorage.setItem('sold', 'true');
             save("isUnlocked", true);
             $state.go("12")
         }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(err);
        $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Something went wrong',
          template: 'Check your console log for the error details'
        });
      });
  };
```

Comment: [joke] The user is charged twice for only one app. I don't understand what is your problem ? [/joke]

Comment: Is it a consumable or non-consumable purchase?  For a non-consumable purchase they will not be charged a second time

Comment: @Paulw11 it is a managed product. (Android)

Comment: I don't know what that is. You have tagged iOS. As well. I was referring to the iOS products